# Right Outer join and inner join use three select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, left-join, outer-join

hello i how can i join tow table  as a  right outer join and left outer join

```
select * 
from 
        (select * 
        from 
                ( select 
                        max(challanno) as mc, 
                        itemid 
                from 
                        tablepurchasedetails 
                group by 
                        itemid 
                ) e
        inner join 
                ( select * from tablepurchasedetails 
                ) m on e.mc = m.CHALLANNO and e.itemid=m.itemid 
        )         tab1
right outer join
        (select 
                v_balance.itemid, 
                v_balance.p_total 
        from 
                v_balance 
        group by 
                v_balance.itemid, 
                v_balance.p_total 
        ) x ; on tab1.itemid=x.itemid;
```

Comment: show us the table structure with sample data and a sample of what you want it to look like. No one will touch a question like this because we are just guessing at what you want

Comment: What happened when you tried?Apart from it complaining about the extra semicolon you have in the middle of the last line?

Comment: replace `) x ; on tab1.itemid=x.itemid;` by `) x  on tab1.itemid=x.itemid;`

Comment: Switch to LEFT JOIN. It's much easier to understand `main table left join optional data` instead of `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: just i have join  three table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello you need a  create view as first query :

> ```
>  select 
>                         max(challanno) as mc, 
>                         itemid 
>                 from 
>                         tablepurchasedetails 
>                 group by 
>                         itemid
> ```

then   join another select statement with view ,